# How I can create a PHP breadcrumb with $_GET

Tags: php

In my index.php, I use this method to generate my pages:

```
<?php
    $pages = scandir("views/");

    if(isset($_GET["p"]) && !empty($_GET["p"]) && in_array($_GET["p"].".php", $pages))
    {
        $page = $_GET["p"];
    }
    else
    {
        header("Location: ?p=home");
    }

    ob_start();
    include "views/$page.php";
    $content = ob_get_clean();
    include "views/layout.php";
?>
```

I would like to create a breadcrumb like this:

[image: breadcrumb]

How can I do that please? Using what I have in my index.php

Comment: rendering HTML directly from user input is very risky as it allows malicious users to inject pretty much anything into your web pages including javascript malware.  You might want to fundamentally rethink your approach

Comment: He Is not doing anything such (in the code sample he provided). He Is checking the value against a set of possible values. May not be best but no security issue with that.

Comment: This is not what I intend to do, I have a layout file in which I include my HTML structure

Comment: In my HTML structure, I would like to include a breadcrumb